# wpf user control to display on top of current view

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I wish to have a user control in my application. The behavior should be similar to a tooltip. That means, when I move the mouse inside my view, this user control also moves.
How to achieve this.
 I do not wish to have draggable canvas, just that the top and left of the control change. Actually what i wish to achieve is quite similar to a [magnifier](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/04/05/using-a-behavior-to-magnify-your-wpf-applications.aspx). But instead of displaying a digital zoom image I wish to display a cropped image inside the magnify viewer.

Comment: I suggest you to use the Popup control to host your usercontrol over your view. Move the popup using its placement properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Adorner` class. Hope this solves your problem.

[Adorner Class Description (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/ms743737.aspx)